# Implement Login in Sub-domain

Tags: php, asp.net, login-script

I found that many sites using sub-domain to handle login. one of them is msn.com. Can anyone explain what is the purpose and advantage of using sub-domain to handle login. Appreciate for any reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers may vary.

One possible reason is that when you forward someone to a login sub-domain, since a lot of websites are using SSL these days (https), there is a good chance that they'll buy an SSL certificate that specifically articulates to that particular login sub-domain.

Another reason is that the login sub-domain could act as a login handler for multiple referring sub-domains across the spectrum of the entire domain in general. For example, (and to get very technical too) a given website located at meta.example.com could forward to login.example.com/?ref=meta, which would be the location of the login handling, which takes in the referring sub-domain and sets a cookie for that referring sub-domain.

But, again, answers may vary. Perhaps this isn't the best StackExchange sub-site for this question.